# Getting a value from a session not working - is it a problem of getting it or passing it?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, cookies

When a user logs into my website, I set a session like this:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["button"])) {
$email = $_POST["email"];
$lozinka = $_POST["lozinka"];

$korisnik = new Korisnik(1, "", "", $email, $lozinka);
$odgovor = Korisnik::prijava($email, $konekcija);
$rez = $odgovor->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
$lozinka = $rez["lozinka"] ?? " ";
$korisnikID = $rez["korisnikID"] ?? " ";

if (!password_verify($_POST["lozinka"], $lozinka)) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
           window.onload = function () { alert("Pogrešno uneti podaci!"); } 
          </script>'; 
} else {
    $_SESSION["korisnik"] = $korisnikID;
    setcookie("korisnik", $korisnikID, time() + 3600);
    header("Location: glavna.php");
    exit();
}
}
```

When I try to extract the value on the main page and forward it into an JQuery function so I could get tasks that the user created to display them, I do it like this:

```
session_start();


if (isset($_COOKIE["korisnik"])) {
    $korisnik = $_COOKIE["korisnik"];
}

[...]

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function vratiZadatke() {
        let izvrsen = "0";
        let kategorija = "0";
        let korisnik = $korisnik;
        $.ajax({
            url: "../funkcije/vratiZadatke.php",
            data: {
                izvrsen: izvrsen,
                kategorija: kategorija,
                korisnik: korisnik
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#zadaci").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
    vratiZadatke();
</script>
```

The `vratiZadatke.php` file looks like this:

```
$izvrsen = trim($_GET["izvrsen"]);
$kategorija = trim($_GET["kategorija"]);
$korisnik = trim($_GET["korisnik"]);

$zadaci = Zadatak::vratiZadatke($izvrsen, $kategorija, $korisnik, $konekcija);
```

I've tried displaying the data without the user ID in the SQL query and it works, but this creates a problem for me and none of the data gets displayed. That's why I won't be sharing that part of the code unless needed. What could be the problem here?

Comment: `let korisnik = $korisnik;` of course will **not** work, you are trying to access $korisnik (a PHP variable) by JS but without the proper code such as `let korisnik = "<?php echo $korisnik; ?>";`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize what I was doing. It's not working on another function I'm trying to call when sending the $korisnik value directly - `session_start(); if (isset($_COOKIE["korisnik"])) { $korisnik = $_COOKIE["korisnik"];} $zadaci = Zadatak::vratiZadatkeZaOpcije($korisnik, $konekcija);` It doesn't seem to register it. What is the problem here? @KenLee

Comment: Most likely you have not set the cookie correctly. By the way, there is no point to switch between session and cookie (I think in your case it is not needed) , I think you can replace `$_COOKIE["korisnik"]` to `$_SESSION["korisnik"]` in all your code and remove the line `setcookie("korisnik", $korisnikID, time() + 3600);` .